# Generic child class and type inference - is this the only way?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

**Update:** I ended up using this article on functional approaches to error handling in C# http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/20/functional-c-handling-failures-input-errors/

I've got a non-generic base class and a generic class inheriting the base class. The purpose of them is to model a "success or failure" idea - sometimes something will return a "I was successful" result and other times something will return a "I was successful and here is the result", though that's not really relevant to the question.

```
public class OperationResult
{
    public bool Successful { get; protected set; }
    public string FailureMessage { get; protected set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; protected set; }

    protected OperationResult() { }

    public static OperationResult Success()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
        return new OperationResult()
        {
            Successful = true
        };
    }
    // not including failure part for clarity
}

public class OperationResult<T> : OperationResult
{
    public T Result { get; private set; }

    private OperationResult () { }

    public static OperationResult<T> Success(T result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(2);
        return new OperationResult<T>()
        {
            Successful = true,
            Result = result
        };
    }
}
```

The situation I've got now is that because both of the methods are named the same, the compiler can no longer infer the type so I need to specify the type. For example:

```
OperationResult.Success(); // Valid
OperationResult.Success("test"); // Invalid
OperationResult<string>.Success("test"); // Valid - wouldn't usually need to specify T
```

I can't help but feel I'm doing something wrong or that there is a better way to do this.

1. Is there a way for the compiler to still infer the type without me specifying it?
2. This is the first time I have seen `Thing<T>.SomeMethod()` syntax (without brackets `()`) - am I going about this totally wrong?

**Edit**: Second attempt with no static convenience methods.

```
new OperationResult().Success();
new OperationResult<string>().Success("something was successful");

public class OperationResult
{
    public bool Successful { get; protected set; }
    public string FailureMessage { get; protected set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; protected set; }

    public OperationResult() { }

    public OperationResult Success()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
        return new OperationResult()
        {
            Successful = true
        };
    }
}

public class OperationResult<T> : OperationResult
{
    public T Result { get; private set; }

    public OperationResult () { }

    public OperationResult<T> Success(T result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(2);
        return new OperationResult<T>()
        {
            Successful = false,
            Result = result
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, the design doesn't look right to me. `static` methods don't go well with inheritance. Is there a reason why you made the `Success` function `static`?

Comment: Racil is right, a static method in a class code smell. It tells you the method does not have a reason to belong in the class. Do a search for "code smells".

Comment: I've added a second attempt that does not use statics. @RacilHilan

Comment: The problem now is that an instance of OperationResult can be called without calling Success.

Comment: Move the Success method into the base class and declare it as `public static OperationResult<T> Success<T>(T result)`. You'll have to make the constructor of OperationResult<T> internal or public. This is a common pattern. It is used for example by the framework's Task and `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to use inheritance to implement two distinctly types of operations. If I understand the application correctly, if it did compile, then you could call either Success method on any operations even though only one is valid. That is, an operation will or will not return a result. So you have 2 different operations.

The compiler issues are a symptom of a design problem.

Design your classes so that they can only be used the right way. That is, never expose methods that should not be called. Here, the intent is to have 2 Success methods, but only one is valid. That is a code smell.

I think the problem arises from inappropriate use of inheritance here.

Approaches:

1. Abstract base class and 2 inherited classes. No Success method in the base class.
2. 2 classes, a common interface and 2 derived interfaces. Inject common functionality in the constructor.

The later is preferred if you value unit testable code. Both are valid, I would do the later.

Comment: In this design it's valid to call `Success` either with a result or not (e.g. think HTTP 200 - there's usually no result data). I've added a second version without the use of statics. I'm definitely interested in the second approach you mentioned, would it be too much to ask for an example of that, if that's OK? I'm struggling to visualise how that would work for this.

Comment: (and the original intent of the statics was to make it impossible to new up OperationResult as the constructor was `protected` - which is now possible unfortunately in the second attempt)

Comment: Hi user993 - If the operation does not return data ... why would you call the method that gives a data type? That is __wrong__. The problem is yes "you could", but you should not. Dunno why I got a down vote ...oh well. If it does return data then why would you call the one that does not give data?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

```
public class OperationResult
{
    public bool Successful { get; protected set; }
    public string FailureMessage { get; protected set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; protected set; }

    protected OperationResult() { }

    public static OperationResult Success()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
        return new OperationResult() { Successful = true };
    }

    public static OperationResult<T> Success<T>(T result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(2);
        return new OperationResult<T>(result) { Successful = true };
    }
}

public class OperationResult<T> : OperationResult
{
    internal OperationResult(T result) { Result = result; }

    public T Result { get; private set; }
}
```

All three of your success lines of code work now.

Comment: While this code does answer the immediate question of how to get it to compile it does not give good design advice. The used of statics does not fit with OO here.

Comment: @RobSmyth - I don't think the OP is concerned about that level of OO. I think in this case it is distracting from the issue at hand. Nevertheless, could you please show the code in your answer that you feel would resolve this for the OP that is using proper OO?

Comment: @RacilHilan - What's terrible about it? And, yes, I have used this kind of thing before. I felt that Rob missed the point on this one.

Comment: @RacilHilan - There's no static constructor and this isn't a singleton. What am I missing?

Comment: @RacilHilan - It looks like a generic message object to me - nothing to do with being a singleton. Each created instance can have a different message - not a singleton at all.

Comment: You're really missing the point here and focusing on non-important details. Maybe my fault :(. OK, forget what I said, let's say I was wrong, so I deleted all my comments. Let's start over and focus on your answer. Let's go back to the OOP basics ;). An `Animal` can `Eat`. A `Dog` is an `Animal`, so it can `Eat`. Cool! Now the `Dog` also `Barks`. With your solution, the `Animal` also `Dog.Barks`, very interesting indeed! And if we're to get a `Cat`, it will also `Dog.Barks`!!! Now, how does that sound? We all should be grateful that nature doesn't use such code :)

Comment: @RacilHilan - Please don't delete comments. It really makes it hard to follow the conversation.

Comment: @RacilHilan - This isn't what's going on here at all. This is about polymorphism and not inheritance. This is a case where the OP wants a generic class `OperationResult<T>`, but wants to be able to pass it around without knowing the type `T` - so he's created a `OperationResult` that doesn't have the `<T>` and this then must become the parent class to allow the polymorphism. Then, for convenience, the `OperationResult` class has a method to create the generic version of itself.

Comment: @RacilHilan - All of this is exactly analogous to the `Task` and `Task<T>` classes in the framework. The `Task` class has a `Run<T>` method to create `Task<T>` instances.

Comment: Well, now we're getting closer with your last comment, so I will skip the previous two (oh, I delete obsolete comments to keep the thread clean, SO is not a conversational platform) . Yes, `Task` and `Task<T>`, except that this is **NOT** how they are implemented. Read the comment by Mike Z below the question. You're base class should have all the static methods and should not call static methods in the derived class ;). That's all. Then I will be your friend again :)

Comment: @RacilHilan - Are you suggesting that it should be like my edit?

Comment: Exactly!!! I mean, look at it; don't you think that it even looks prettier? :). And now you will not be killing a kitten by making her bark like a dog :). If you like, you can add a brief explanation (perhaps from our comments), and we can delete our comments to keep the thread clean.

Comment: @RacilHilan - I don't like the `internal` constructor. I think that breaks encapsulation.

Comment: I don't particularly like it either, but we can never get everything we want, can we? But if my only two options are to either grossly violate the OOD or use `internal`, I choose the later. Anyway, I'm not a big fan of the `Result` pattern. The link at the top of the question provides compelling arguments for it, which I myself liked and tried in the past, but then bounced back to the `Exceptions` pattern in general and use simple `Result` pattern in very limited cases. I found that using comments to enhance readability is better than the risks of a global `Result` pattern.

Comment: And by the way, that article is more than 3 years old. With the new C# features, one can now use a `Tuple` to return a `Result` along with the value object instead of `Result<T>`. I'm not saying it is better, but it's a new option than should be considered and evaluated. I haven't evaluated it myself yet, because like I said, I'm no longer a big fan of a global `Result` pattern, but I definitely prefer using a `Tuple` if needed in some of the limited cases where I use the `Result` pattern.